# How can I run Junit test case on Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc, junit4

I created a test case using Selenium IDE and exported it to Junit. When I run my TestCase1.java file I get the following errors and so I am not able to proceed.

C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.5.0_06\bin>javac c:\acceptance-tests\TestCase1.java
c:\acceptance-tests\TestCase1.java:1: package org.openqa.selenium.server does no exist
import org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteControlConfiguration;
                                  ^
c:\acceptance-tests\TestCase1.java:2: package org.openqa.selenium.server does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;
                                  ^
c:\acceptance-tests\TestCase1.java:3: package com.thoughtworks.selenium does not exist
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

and

When I attempt to run Junit tests on Selenium RC, I get the following message:
"package junit.framewo rk.Test does not exist import junit.framework.Test.*;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add both the Selenium Client Drivers and JUnit library files to your classpath. You can get these from http://www.seleniumhq.org and http://www.junit.org 
When running tests through JUnit you need to connect to a running Selenium RC server. You can start the server programmatically or run the selenium-server jar. Both of these methods are [documented here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html).